# DML in a future method will be rollback if after there's a throw exception

Tags: exception, future

My classA calls classB which calls a future method inserting an object, later in classA it throws an exception, and I saw my DML in future method is also being rollbacked. Is there anyway to commit insert even if later there's an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your interpretation is not quite correct. When a future method, or any other Asynchronous Apex, is enqueued in a transaction that is later interrupted by an unhanded exception, the *enqueuing of the future method itself* is rolled back. The Asynchronous Apex never in fact runs.

If you wish to have asynchronous functionality execute regardless of any unhandled exceptions thrown later in the same transaction, you can publish a Platform Event (with behavior set to Publish Immediately). That operation is non-transactional, so it happens immediately and is not rolled back. Your automation can then react to that Platform Event.

This strategy has relatively few use cases, logging being a major one. Consider carefully whether you *really* want to create non-transactional behavior in your org before you go down this road.

Comment: Yes, the plateform even is a good solution, thanks David

Answer (score 1):

Future methods does processing in asynchronous manner. Asynchronous processing will let the current thread gets completed and when the system is available it does the processing.

So according to your scenario if ClassA -> ClassB -> Future method. So as soon as the future method being called from ClassB it will wait flex queue to get executed until the resource is available.
Also post future method being called from ClassB if there is any logic needs to be processed by ClassB and ClassA it will get processed before even the future method will run.

So if there is any exceptions in ClassA it won't rollback the data getting processed in future method dml.

ClassA + ClassB will be in same transaction whereas Future method will be a separate transaction.

Comment: Thanks Ranjit, as you said Future method is in a separate transaction so even there's exception in classA won't rollback DML, but what I saw is DML being rollbacked

Comment: The reason could be that your future method has not run since there is an exception ClassA... Monitor whether the future method even executed successfully or not will make you conclude exact reason.